# JavaScript and/or JavaScript code using jquery invoking WCF Service retrieving a collection of System.IO.Stream?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, collections, stream

I am creating a WCF service that will be consumed by plain JavaScript on the client side and some jQuery JavaScript on the client side as well.

1) How can I implement the plain client JavaScript so that it will invoke the WCF Service in such a way that it will retrieve a collection of System.IO.Stream at once? Moreover, how would I iterate through the collection that was received on the plain JavaScript side in such a way that I can associate each of the System.IO.Stream objects in the collection to an HTML image element?

2) Is it possible to implement the JavaScript code that uses jquery so that it will invoke the WCF Service in such a way that it will retrieve a collection of System.IO.Stream at once? Moreover, how would I iterate through the collection that was received by the JavaScript that uses jQuery in such a way that I can associate each of the System.IO.Stream objects in the collection to an HTML image element?

```
 /*********Start of Excerpt from the Interface Code of a WCF Service 

  Contract*****************/ 

  using System; 

  using System.Collections.Generic; 

  using System.Linq; 

  using System.Runtime.Serialization; 

  using System.ServiceModel; 

  using System.ServiceModel.Activation; 

  using System.Text; 

  using System.ServiceModel.Web; 

  using System.IO; 

  using ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial.PerlsDataContracts; 

  using ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial.DataAccessObjectsDAO; 


  namespace ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial 

  { 

     [ServiceContract(Namespace = 

  "http://ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial.CarService")] 

     public interface ICarService 

     { 

    [OperationContract] 

    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 

                    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)] 

         Stream[] getImagesList(); 




     } 

  } 

  /*********End of Excerpt from the Interface Code of a WCF Service 
  Contract*****************/ 




  /*********Start of Excerpt of the code associated with the Class that 
  implements the WCF Service Contract*****************/ 

  using System; 
  using System.Collections.Generic; 
  using System.Linq; 
  using System.Text; 
  using System.Collections; 
  using System.ServiceModel.Activation; 
  using System.Configuration; 
  using System.Data; 
  using System.IO; 
  using System.ComponentModel; 
  using ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial.PerlsDataContracts; 
  using ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial.DataAccessObjectsDAO; 


  namespace ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial 
  { 
       [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
       AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.NotAllowed)] 
  class CarService : ICarService 
  { 

        public Stream[] getImagesList() 
         { 


             List<Stream> myImagesList = new List<Stream>(); 

             string fileName = Path.Combine("BMWpicture.jpg"); 

             FileStream fileStream = 
               new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
             // Set the content type as image/ jpeg 
             System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext. 
               Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 


             myImagesList.Add(fileStream); 

             string fileName2 = Path.Combine     ("MercedesBenzpicture.jpg"); 

             FileStream fileStream2 = 
          new FileStream(fileName2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
             // Set the content type as image/ jpeg 
             System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext. 
               Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 


             myImagesList.Add(fileStream2); 

             return myImagesList.ToArray(); 
         } 
     } 
  } 
  /*********End of Excerpt of the code associated with the Class that 
  implements the WCF Service Contract*****************/ 


  <!--Start of Excerpt of the plain JavaScript client code that 
  invokes one of the Methods in the WCF Service 
  Contract--> 

  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  function getImagesList2() { 

    var listOfStreams = 
  'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial/c     arService     /getImagesList' 

    document.getElementById("image11").onload = function () { 
      }; // img.onload = function() 


  document.getElementById("image11").src = listOfStreams[0]; 



    document.getElementById("image12").onload = function () { 
         }; // img.onload = function() 


       document.getElementById("image12").src = listOfStreams[1]; 

  } 
  </script> 
  <!--End of Excerpt of the plain JavaScript client code that 
  invokes one of the Methods in the WCF Service 
  Contract--> 

  <!--Start of Excerpt of the HTML code that is affected by the 
  JavaScript client and WCF Service interaction--> 
  <body> 
     <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
     <div> 


                  <img src=""  id="image11" alt="Smiley face" />      

                <img src=""  id="image12" alt="Smiley face" /> 


          <br /> 
          <a class="large blue button" id="A7" 
  onClick="getImagesList2()">getImagesList2</a> 


         </div> 
     </form> 
  </body> 
  </html> 

  <!--End of Excerpt of the HTML code that is affected by the 
 JavaScript client and WCF Service interaction-->
```

1) How can I implement the plain client JavaScript so that it will invoke the WCF Service in such a way that it will retrieve a collection of System.IO.Stream at once? Moreover, how would I iterate through the collection that was received on the plain JavaScript side in such a way that I can associate each of the System.IO.Stream objects in the collection to an HTML image element?

2) Is it possible to implement the JavaScript code that uses jquery so that it will invoke the WCF Service in such a way that it will retrieve a collection of System.IO.Stream at once? Moreover, how would I iterate through the collection that was received by the JavaScript that uses jQuery in such a way that I can associate each of the System.IO.Stream objects in the collection to an HTML image element?

Comment: Returning a file system access object from server to client doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Pointy I'm basically trying to create some kind of image gallery that would have javaScript and/or jquery on the client side, and C# code on the server side.  May I please know how I can send images like jpegs from server to client( in such a way that I can avoid sending file system access object from server to client )?

Comment: If you're talking about a web browser client, can't you just use `<img>` tags?

Comment: @Pointy My JavaScript needs to invoke a C# WCF Service with some arguments that would determine the types of images returned.  I do use the img tags but the jpegs associated with the image tags would change.  My original intention was to use the JavaScript to invoke a C# WCF Service with some arguments so that it will return some System.IO.Stream collection which would ultimately be jpegs for my gallery.

Comment: If by "client" you're talking about a web browser, then you can't return streams; it just doesn't make sense. You have to provide URLs for the client to access the images, and the URLs can map to server-side actions that dynamically determine the image data with which to respond.

Comment: Some things just make my scratch my head a LOT in wonder when I read them...this strategy may be one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for doesn't really make sense to use in the scheme you have specified. You are already fetching the URLs to the images, just send over an array of the paths, and build images on the client. You have jQuery on your page, so Ajax requests would be simple enough. Something like this should give you a push in the right direction:

```
// return this from the server:
{ "data" : [ "path/to/image1.jpg", "path/to/image2.jpg" ] }

// then consume in your response on the client side:
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ConsoleForWCFServiceTutorial/carService/getImagesList',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response) {
        var container = $("<div/>");
        $.each( response.data, function (value, index) {
            container.append("<img src='" + value "' />");
        });

        container.prependTo("#form1");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.Therefore, in the case of the sample code that you gave, there would be No jpeg files coming from the WCF service side.In other words, I would only be getting text or json information from the WCF service.There are No Streams from WCF Service side. Would this be an accurate description of what you are saying?

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying.